# Is the initialization of a variable a statement or an expression?

Tags: java, initialization, expression

```
class Demo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          int a; // declaration statement

          a = 5; // initialization statement/expression?
     }
}
```

I've looked into it, and it seems to be both a statement AND an expression. Is this true? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: I'd suspect the best documentation for this would be the JLS. My guess is that `a = ____` is a statement, while `5` is an expression, but until I find something backing that up, take that with a large grain of salt.

Comment: Is this as a local variable, or an instance variable?

Comment: @JonSkeet Local variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A local variable declaration - with or without initialization - is a statement, as specified in [section 14.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4).

It's important to note that this is *not* an expression in the way that a simple assignment expression is - you can't use it as part of a larger statement (other than a block). For example:

```
int x;
System.out.println(x = 5); // Prints 5

System.out.println(int x = 10); // Invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

Assignments are both expressions and statements in Java. The value of the assignment is the value assigned to its variable. This allows you to do multiple assignments, such as:

```
a = b = 5;
```

The assignment `b = 5` is treated as an expression whose value is 5, so that value can be assigned to `a` in the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any documentation on this?

It might help you [Oracle Doc - Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

#### Expression

An expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value.

#### Statements

Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of expressions can be made into a statement by *terminating the expression with a semicolon (;)*.

- Assignment expressions
- Any use of ++ or --
- Method invocations
- Object creation expressions

Such statements are called **expression** statements.

In addition to *expression* statements, there are two other kinds of statements:

1. declaration statements
2. control flow statements

A declaration statement declares a variable. For example

```
// declaration statement
double aValue = 8933.234;
```

#### Blocks

A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

An *assignment* is a *statement*. It saves the result of the *expression* on the right side to the variable on the left side.